# Directory Listing Denied in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

I have a new Orchard site which successfully runs the setup and database configuration when running locally.  But when I tried to deploy it to the actual server and point a browser to the site, I get a "Directory Listing Denied" error.

Anyone seen this and fixed it?

Comment: Is there a version mismatch between the local and deployment servers? Does the deployed server have Url rewrite enabled? Those would be my first 2 questions.

Comment: I would also recommend deploying the base package straight from the zip or WebPI to the server and seeing if that works.

Comment: @NickDaniels Good call. Extensionless URLs were another problem that had to be solved. Got through that issue, then this one popped up.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.  Running on a shared web server, if IIS is configured for my site to use the default app pool, Orchard is precluded from reading its own files.  (Remember that Orchard uses libraries and needs deep read/write access to subdirectories).

So the solution was simply to configure the site to run in its own isolated application pool.

Looks like this on my site's control panel:

[image]

Hope this solution helps someone down the line.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you deployed the whole source code instead of src/orchard.web.